# Prove that $f$ is Borel measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a ﬁnite Borel measure on $\mathbb R$, i.e. a ﬁnite measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $S (\mathbb R)$,
and let $B$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$. Deﬁne the function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ by $f (x) =\mu (B + x)$.

(a) Show that $f$ is Borel measurable.
(b) Show that $\int f (x) d\lambda (x) =\int f (x) dx =\mu(R)\lambda(B)$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure

I am not able to prove that $f$ is Borel measurable. I tried to prove that $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is a Borel set but couldn't prove it.

Comment: Can you do it in case $B$ is an open interval?

Comment: I tried that but I still couldn't do it.

Comment: A still easier case is $B=(a,b)$ but also $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$ for all $x$.  Can you prove $f$ is Borel measurable in that case?

Comment: I cant't do that either.

Comment: I was able to get part a). Can some one help me with part b)

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, notice that $f(x)=\int \chi_B(s-x)\mathrm d\mu(s)$. We then use Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the product measure $\mu\times\lambda$ in $\mathbb R^2$ and integrate the clearly $\mu\times\lambda$-measurable function $F(x,y)=\chi_B(x-y)$. Fubini's Theorem answers both question. (See the version of Fubini's Theorem in Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis.)